# Using System.Data.Sqlclient instead of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient when connecting to a Fabric datawarehouse

Tags: vb.net, system.data, microsoft-fabric

Using this example:
https://robkerr.ai/query-fabric-table-csharp/

I can connect to my sqlserver Fabric Warehouse in Azure trough VS Code when using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient`

My question is this : Is this possible to achive using `System.Data.SqlClient`?
I just can't make it work.

(This is part of a rather big solution and using `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` raises all kind of other problems)

This code works fine

```
Imports Microsoft.Data.SqlClient
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=theCave.datawarehouse.pbidedicated.windows.net,1433;
                               Initial Catalog=TreASURE;
                               Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;
                               User Id=AliBaba@robber.no;  
                               Password=SesamSesam"

Dim conn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
conn.Open()
```

But when replacing `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` with `System.Data.Sqlclient` I just cant make it work.

tnx

Comment: *"I just cant make it work"* is not a problem description. You ALWAYS need to explain EXACTLY what actually happens.

Comment: The ActiveDirectoryPassword auth flow is blocked by many tenants by policy.  You may have to use an interactive auth flow, or use a Service Prinicpal.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both System.Data.SqlClient and Microsoft.Data.SqlClient can connect to Fabric SQL endpoints.

Fabric SQL endpoints don't support SQL Auth or Windows Auth. Only Entra ID auth (formerly called AAD auth).

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient natively understands and implements several EntraId authentication flows.  System.Data.SqlClient only understands a couple of Entra ID auth flows natively.  But you can fetch an access token for Azure SQL Database using any auth flow you need, and set the .AccessToken property on a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to connect.

Follow the docs here: [Connect using a Microsoft Entra ID access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#microsoft-entra-id-access-token)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the NuGet reference for this: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=SqlClient

I see:
[image]

The important part being:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

> The current data provider for SQL Server and Azure SQL databases.

There is no such assertion for System.Data.SqlClient.

Therefore, I think it is safe to assume that `System.Data.SqlClient` does not work with Azure.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient does work with Azure! Tweeking around with the connetionstring It suddenly worked. I can hear Angel trumpets!!